# How do i join 2 tables together, getting just one row of values from the 2nd table out of duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, the 1st table (withdrawn) and the 2nd table (operative).
One of the columns in the withdrawn table is called 'reference', the reference column sometimes has duplicate values (which its supposed to). The operative table columns are id (which is exactly the same as the reference column in the withdrawn table), name and depot. I need to keep the 1st table exactly the same size as it already is (in row numbers) but add the name and depot numbers from the operative table.

NOTE: in the operative table, the name and depot columns will always be the exact same for each individual id number.

The problem im having when i try LEFT JOIN, is that the query duplicates all the rows many times over. I think this is because the operative table contains the same id value in many different rows

```sql
SELECT * FROM withdrawn

LEFT JOIN operative ON id = reference
```

I want the query to return

```
reference    depot     name
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
```

what i get is something like

```
reference    depot     name
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
1            101       John Smith
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
2            102       Sam Turner
```

Comment: Your desired output still has duplicates.

Comment: mysql <> sql server, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Maybe the way your tables are designed, you might need to join on an additional condition? Like: `LEFT JOIN operative ON id = reference AND col2 = col3` ? Maybe the tables (1:m relationship) are fine and you just need to use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @SeanLange It still has duplicates but they are the duplicates that are already in the withdrawn table, which is what i want

Comment: @Andrew Im using microsoft sql server management studio. But plan on moving the finished query to an excel data connection

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu the problem with that is the id column is the only column that matches up exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. I tried a few of the methods but didn't get the exact result i was looking for. Finally figured it out, it was really simple.

```
SELECT * FROM WITHDRAWN
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT o.reference, o.depot, o.name FROM OPERATIVE)  OPERATIVE ON w.reference = o.reference
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get distinct values from that second table in a subquery. Your subquery will have 1 row for each distinct `reference, depot` combo. That will `LEFT OUTER JOIN` nicely and assuming that your `reference`:`depot` is 1:1 in that `operative` table you should get your desired output.

```
SELECT * 
FROM withdrawn
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT reference, depot FROM operative) op ON withdrawn.id = op.reference
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should suffice for your scenario:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    w.reference
    , w.depot
    , o.name 
FROM withdrawn w
    LEFT JOIN operative o 
        ON o.id = w.reference
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT w.*, o.depot
FROM withdrawn w OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) o.*
      FROM operative
      WHERE o.id = w.reference
     ) ;
```

This returns an arbitrary matching row.  You can use an `ORDER BY` in the subquery if you want a particular row (such as the oldest or newest).